# AOSP How to verify OTA updates by their metadata

Tags: updates, android-source, ota

I'm building an OTA update for my custom Android 10 build as follows:

```
./build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files \
  --output_metadata_path metadata.txt \
  target-files.zip \
  ota.zip
```

The resulting ota.zip can be applied by extracting the payload.bin and payload_properties.txt according to the android documentation for update_engine_client.

```
update_engine_client --payload=file:///<wherever>/paypload.bin \
   --update \
   --headers=<Contents of payload_properties.txt>
```

This all works so I'm pretty sure from this result that I've created the OTA correctly, however, I'd like to be able to download the metadata and verify that the payload can be applied before having the client download the entire payload.

Looking at the update_engine_client --help options, it appears one can verify the metadata as follows:

```
update_engine_client --verify --metadata=<path to metadata.txt from above>
```

This is where I'm failing to achieve the desired result though.  I get an error that says it failed to parse the payload header.  It's failing with `kDownloadInvalidMetadataMagicString` which when I read the source appears to be the first 4 bytes of the metadata.  Apparently the metadata.txt I created isn't right for the verification tool.

So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to either generate the metadata correctly or tell me how to use the tool correctly.

Comment: 0911/160344.475208:INFO:delta_performer.cc(208)] Completed 0/? operations, 16264/927311316 bytes downloaded (0%), overall progress 0%
[0911/160344.475270:ERROR:payload_metadata.cc(74)] Bad payload format -- invalid delta magic.
[0911/160344.475295:ERROR:download_action.cc(336)] Error ErrorCode::kDownloadInvalidMetadataMagicString (21) in DeltaPerformer's Write method when processing the received payload -- Terminating processing
[0911/160344.475329:INFO:delta_performer.cc(313)] Discarding 24 unused downloaded bytes

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the metadata generated by the ota tool is in human readable format.  The verify method expects a binary file. That file is not part of the zip contents as a unique file. Instead, it's prepended to the payload.bin.  So the first bytes of payload.bin are actually payload_metadata.bin, and those bytes will work correctly with the verify method of update_engine_client to determine if the payload is applicable.

I'm extracting the payload_metadata.bin in a makefile as follows:

```
$(DEST)/%.meta: $(DEST)/%.zip
    unzip $< -d /tmp META-INF/com/android/metadata 
    python -c 'import re; meta=open("/tmp/META-INF/com/android/metadata").read(); \
              m=re.match(".*payload_metadata.bin:([0-9]*):([0-9]*)", meta); \
              s=int(m.groups()[0]); l=int(m.groups()[1]); \
              z=open("$<","rb").read(); \
              open("$@","wb").write(z[s:s+l])'
    rm -rf /tmp/META-INF
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  This bit of information is GOLD!  Made my day.